# How to get object property from a collection

Tags: c#, object

In order to eliminate the need to write a really long Switch Statement, I want to get the object property from a collection that contains data.

Here is my code:

```
public class NCAABArchive 
{
    private int id;
    public int HScore;
    public string Road;
    public int RScore;
    public double Line;
    public double LineAvg;
    public double LineSag;
    public double LineSage;
    public double LineSagp;
    public double LineSggm;
    public double LineMoore;


}


        string forecastStr = "coll.LineFox";
        string actualStr = "coll.ActualSpread";

        foreach (NCAABArchive coll in Form1.gui.NCAABArchiveCollection)
        {
            recCtr++;
```

//System.NullReferenceException
//  HResult=0x80004003
//  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
//  Source=BBallStatsPredictions

```
            //PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(NCAABArchive).GetProperty(forecastStr);
            //object value = pinfo.GetValue(coll);

            if (recCtr % 100 == 0)
            {
                if (coll.GameScore != null)
                {
                    switch (forecastStr)
                    {
                        case "coll.LineAvg":
                            altargetforecast.Add(coll.LineAvg);
                            break;

                        case "coll.LineSag":
                            altargetforecast.Add(coll.LineSag);
                            break;

                        case "coll.LineSggm":
                            altargetforecast.Add(coll.LineSggm);
                            break;

                        case "coll.LineFox":
                            altargetforecast.Add(coll.LineFox);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    //altargetforecast.Add(coll.LineAvg);
                    //alactual.Add(coll.ActualSpread);

                    // altargetforecast.Add(forecastStr);
                    alactual.Add(coll.ActualSpread);
                }
            }
```

I'm getting an Error **Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

How do I instantiate the object,  the collection already is instantiated?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whinch line in this code is the null reference exception being raised?

Comment: after I un-comment and run the "object value=pinfo line. I get the error

Answer (score 0):

Your forecastStr is not the property name.  It is "coll.{propertyname}".

The problem is that your line:

PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(NCAABArchive).GetProperty(forecastStr);

is not getting a property because there's not a property called "coll.Linefox".

So pinfo is null and returning the error when you try to access it.

```
string propName = "LineAvg"
PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(NCAABArchive).GetProperty(propName);
object value = pinfo.GetValue(coll)

// "value" will be set to coll.LineAvg
```

Comment: Still getting the error:  System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at the pinfo.GetValue(coll)  line.

Comment: Where are you getting the error.  On the GetProperty line, or the GetValue line?  If the latter, check if pinfo is null.

Comment: Neil, I'm getting the error on the GetValue line.  Error says "pinfo is null"

Comment: And what is your "forecastStr" set to at the time?